# Character moving through walls

Tags: python, tkinter, collision

I've made some progress with my maze game. 
However, there is one problem that is quite persistent : the character is moving correctly now but it is also moving through walls.
It's quite annoying and I'd like to know if there is a simple command to prevent it from doing so. (I've already tried with the bbox methode and the find overlapping but I must have done something wrong with them...)
Here's the code :

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame # Note : importation pygame pour pouvoir jouer des sons (musique)/ importing pygame Library to play music



pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("alerte.wav") # musique d'intro/ intro music
pygame.mixer.music.play() 


# Position / fonction that is in charge of moving the character

# Boucle principale / main loop
def Clavier(event) :
    global XP,YP
    touche = event.keysym
    # déplacement vers le haut / moving up
    if touche == 'Up':
        YP -= 20
    # déplacement vers le bas / moving down
    if touche == 'Down':
        YP += 20
    # déplacement vers la droite / moving right
    if touche == 'Right':
        XP += 20
    # déplacement vers la gauche / moving left
    if touche == 'Left':
        XP -= 20
    Fond.coords(Pion,XP -10, YP -10, XP +10, YP +10)
    Fond.update()



def lisDecors(fichier):
    """
    Fonction qui lis le contenu du fichier et la place dans
    la liste 2D Décors / function that reads a file that contains the level and place it in the list that con,tains the 2D background
    """
    filin = open(fichier,'r')
    R = [list(line.replace('\n','')) for line in filin]
    filin.close()
    return R

def dessine():
    """
    Fonction qui dessine le plateau de jeu avec les données de la liste Décors / Function that draws the game's background with the help of the list that contains the 2D background
    """
    ligne, colonne = 0, 0
    while ligne < 17 :
      if Decors[ligne][colonne] == 'X' :
        Fond.create_image(colonne*40, ligne*40, image=X, anchor=NW)
      if Decors[ligne][colonne] == 'T' :
        Fond.create_image(colonne*40, ligne*40, image=T, anchor=NW)
      colonne=colonne+1
      if colonne == 25 :
        colonne = 0
        ligne = ligne + 1


fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.resizable(width=False, height=False)

fenetre.title("Projet Deadalus - Prepare 4 F3AR")
fenetre.geometry("1200x680")
XP, YP = 80, 80

# Dessin de l'interface / Drawing main Canvas
Fond=Canvas(fenetre,width=1200,height=680,bg="#000000")
Pion = Fond.create_oval(XP-10,YP-10,XP+10,YP+10,width=2,outline='black',fill='red')
Fond.place(x=0,y=0)
Fond.focus_set()
Fond.bind('<Key>',Clavier)
Fond.pack(padx =5, pady =5)
Fond.create_rectangle(1000,0,1200,680,fill="black",width=5,outline="black")
Txt=Fond.create_text(1100,275,text="Projet Deadalus",font=("OCRAExtended","15"),fill="#0B0")
Texte=Fond.create_text(1100,300,text="Prepare 4 F3AR",font=("OCRAExtended","15"),fill="#0B0")


# Chargement des fichiers / loading files
T=PhotoImage(file="images/FondS.gif")
X=PhotoImage(file="images/brick.gif")




# On lis le décors. On garde les informations du décors dans une liste pour
# pouvoir tester si on tombe, si on peut monter, .... / Reading background file
Decors = lisDecors('niveaux/niv1.txt')
dessine()







fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please reduce this to the [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Where is the code that is attempting to prevent the character moving through walls? What do you think you did wrong with what you have tried so far?

Comment: You must implement collision detection. There's no "simple command to do so", but the method you mentioned of using bounding boxes to find overlapping regions is a good start, so you may want to ask for help on that - otherwise, this question is probably too broad

Comment: Yeah, I'd like some précisions about the bbox method. My theory is that Tkinter doesn't 'like' .gifs ( the character refused to move until I replaced its .gif with an oval...

Comment: @MaxFR68: your theory that Tkinter doesn't "like" gifs makes no sense. Images are first class citizens with Tkinter. They can be moved as easily as anything else, assuming you are using them properly.